# Efficient 2 dimensional array search in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I am trying to design an application and part of it is to show users new articles in different categories after the last visit of the user to the webapp. To this I use MySql and have a table that keeps track of last visits and I can query the table to get a php array like below:

```
$array =[[user1,category1, datetime1],[user1,category2, datetime2],[user1,category3,datetime3]];
```

Where `user` is the user id and `datetime` is the visited datetime and `category` is the article category.

Having the setup above, I am trying to get new articles from the article table where the publish date is after user last visited to categories.

I can achieve this by multiple OR in a query like below, however it is not really a good and nice looking query, and probable not scalable. Is there any other way of doing this which is simpler and faster?

```
$multiwhere=[];
foreach($array as $a){
$multiwhere[]="select article_id from articles where category=".$a[1]." and publish_date>".$a[2];
}
```

And the final query would be like this:

```
"Select * from articles where article_id in (".implode(" or ".$multiwhere.")";
```

I deeply appreciate any suggestion to improve the query above.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is almost correct, apart from the fact that you first retrieve all the `article_id` you want, and then use them to query for those articles. You can do that in one step, like so:

```php
$multiwhere = [];
foreach ($array as $a) {
    $multiwhere[] = "(category = " . $a[1] . " AND publish_date >= " . $a[2] .")";
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM articles";
if (count($multiwhere) > 0) {
    $query = " WHERE " . implode(" OR ", $multiwhere);
}
```

One query will do.

I kept the way you use the `$array`, but it looks weird to me. Especially around `publish_date`. I cannot change that because I don't know the type of the field. And, of course, `$array` is quite a bad name. It tells you what the type of the variable is, not what it contains, as it should. A better name would be: `$lastCategoryVisits`, or something like that. Your loop should look something like this:

```php
foreach ($lastCategoryVisits as $lastCategoryVisit) {
    $category  = $lastCategoryVisit["category"];
    $lastVisit = $lastCategoryVisit["lastVisit"];
    $QueryConditions[] = "(category = '$category' AND publish_date >= '$lastVisit')";
}
```

Don't be afraid to write out what your code actually does. It might be a bit longer, but now you can see what is going on. This will not slow down the execution of your code at all.

Finally, it would be better to always [use prepared statements to prevent the possibility of SQL-injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). If you get into the habit of always doing this you don't have to use excuses like: *"It is not important in this project."*, *"I'll to it later when the code works."* or *"The data for this query doesn't come from an user."*.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Is there any other way to write this query?

Comment: @MyQ You're welcome. Yes, there might be another way. You could separate the publish dates from the categories. Something like: `category IN (cat1, cat2, ... catN) AND publish_date >= last_visit_date`, but that depends on what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the query in your comment considers only one datetime which may not be the best.

Comment: @MyQ Yes, that's the compromise. It is worth considering whether you would always need to take all the individual dates into consideration. When you have many-many articles and many categories, using `OR` many times in the query, will become inefficient. But I'm talking about thousands of articles and many dozen of categories.